# Column Pair-wise reorganization in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have my data like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,3,3],[2,3,2,4],[4,1,3,2]],columns=['A1','A2','B1','B2'])

df
   A1   A2   B1   B2
0  A:2  A:1  B:3  B:3
1  A:2  A:3  B:2  B:4
2  A:4  A:1  B:3  B:2
```

the value in A1, A2 is one pair, same with B1 and B2.

Now I want to reorganize each pair so they are in alphabet order:

```
df
   A1   A2   B1   B2
0  A:1  A:2  B:3  B:3
1  A:2  A:3  B:2  B:4
2  A:1  A:4  B:2  B:3
```

I can do this with a `for` loop for each pair, sort, and then reparse it into the pandas frame:

```
for index, row_ in df.iterrows():
    for pair_ in range(int(len(row_)/2)):
        print(index, pair_)
        pair = row_[pair_*2:(pair_*2+2)]
        df.iloc[index, pair_*2:(pair_*2+2)] = pair.sort_values()
```

but this seems to be very inefficient.

Please suggest me better approach on this, thank you

Comment: So your data has only 4 columns? Or do you need a more general solution?

Comment: I have more columns than this example, so I need a more general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `np.sort`:

```
# replace with your number
num_col_in_group = 2
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values.reshape(len(df), -1, num_col_in_group), 
                     axis=-1).reshape(len(df),-1), 
             columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
    A1   A2   B1   B2
0  A:1  A:2  B:3  B:3
1  A:2  A:3  B:2  B:4
2  A:1  A:4  B:2  B:3
```

Comment: very neat answer indeed, would you please explain a bit of the idea for me?

Comment: Since each row consists of multiple blocks to be sorted, the idea is to arrange the blocks on the same axis so np.sort can work, sort that axis and the reshape back.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen reshape should be `len(df), -1, num_col_in_group` as updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply take the min and max of 2 columns and re-assign them with that:

```
pairs = (('A1', 'A2'), ('B1', 'B2'))  # or any other way to define the pairs

for c1, c2 in pairs:
    df[c1], df[c2] = np.minimum(df[c1], df[c2]), np.maximum(df[c1], df[c2])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this only work if my group has 2 elements

Answer (score 1):

Quang's solution is pretty neat. Here is a bit of experiment with `wide_to_long`:

```
pair_names = ['A','B']
m = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),pair_names,'index','v').sort_values(by=pair_names)
idx = m.groupby(m.index.get_level_values('index')).cumcount().add(1)

out = m.droplevel('v').set_index(idx,append=True).sort_index('index').unstack()
out.columns = out.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
```

---

```
print(out)

       A1  A2  B1  B2
index                
0       1   2   5   3
1       2   3   2   4
2       1   4   2   3
```